# What does it mean $X^{-2}$ in matrix notation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following equation:
$$GCV(\lambda)=\frac{ n\times\text{trace}\{Y'[I-S_{\phi,\lambda}]^{-2}Y\} }{\{\text{trace}[I-S_{\phi,\lambda}]\}^2}$$

I know $I-S_{\phi,\lambda}$ is a matrix what is the power to the -2 supposed to mean? is it the power of each element?

Comment: I would think it's inverse squared.

Answer (score 2):

I think the natural interpretation of the notation $X^{-2}$ would be the inverse squared.